# I have some problem with turtle color script

Tags: python-3.x

I'm follow a little turtle project from youtube.And i have copy the same code from the video. When i run the code it come out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Tur1.py", line 7, in <module>
JJ.color('red', 'blue')
File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\turtle.py", line 2218, in color
pcolor = self._colorstr(pcolor)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_colorstr
```

**This is my Code:**

```
import turtle
import random
JJ = turtle.Turtle 
colors = ['red', 'blue','green', 'purple', 'yellow', 
'orange','black']
JJ.color('red', 'blue')
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your code is missing the parentheses on the end of its assignment to `JJ`. As a result, `JJ` just contains a reference to the `Turtle` class in the `turtle` module, but does not contain an actual instance of the `Turtle` class (i.e., an instantiated object). (My apologies if you are new to python, in which case I suspect that my explanation might not make a lot of sense to you.)

Short answer/fix, simply rewrite your code as follows:

```
import turtle
import random
JJ = turtle.Turtle()
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'purple', 'yellow', 'orange', 'black']
JJ.color('red', 'blue')
```

*Note that `JJ = turtle.Turtle` has changed to `JJ = turtle.Turtle()` which executes the methods necessary to initialize a Turtle object.*

Comment: oh , i had correction back the line , and yeh, u are right i missing the parentheses. Thanks You! It Fixed.